# Ruby Script Runner for Ubuntu Gedit

Tags: gedit

I have this Java script runner installed in my gedit external tools:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_DIR
if javac $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME;
then
java ${GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME%\.java}
else
echo "Failed to compile"
fi
```

I tried modifying to it to something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_DIR
ruby ${GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME%\.rb}
```

but it doesn't work. I may have missed something, I don't know what because I don't do bash scripting. Hehe

Comment: did you test this in the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hy, I used this and this works fine (I'm using ruby1.9.1 on my ubuntu)

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_DIR
ruby1.9.1 $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME
```

Good luck.